# AudioTrack stopped working on Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, audiotrack, android-5.1.1-lollipop

After getting hold of an Android device with Lollipop, I noticed the AudioTrack code we have working for Kitkat (and previous versions) simply stopped working, the exact same code works well for devices prior to Lollipop, so I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong with the new version.
Here's how the `AudioTrack` (referred by the `mTrack` property), gets initialized:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int bufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    mTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
}
```

And here's how the buffer gets filled in:

```
public void onPlayAudio(byte[] audioBuffer) {
    if (mTrack.getPlayState() != AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING) {
        mTrack.play();
    }

    if (audioBuffer != null) {
        mTrack.write(audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.length);
    }
}
```

Again this is working well with devices prior to Lollipop. There's no errors on Logcat, everything seems to be normal but the sound doesn't come out (yes, I checked the volume and it is all the way up). So I wonder if there was an update I'm missing or rather I'm doing somthing wrong.

I noticed `AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO` got deprecated but trying the suggested `AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO` doesn't seem to do the trick.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: No one has a clue about this? The same exact code works for Kitkat and previous versions. Any changes that need to be applied for Lollipop?

Answer (score 5):

Google Changing API.
Try this:

```
val audioTrack: AudioTrack
        get() = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            AudioTrack(
                    AudioAttributes.Builder()
                            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                            .build(),
                    AudioFormat.Builder()
                            .setSampleRate(FREQUENCY)
                            .setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
                            .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO).build(),
                    SOUND_BUFFER_SIZE,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM,
                    AudioManager.AUDIO_SESSION_ID_GENERATE)
        } else {
            //support for Android KitKat
            AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    FREQUENCY,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    SOUND_BUFFER_SIZE,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM)
        }
```